# orientation problem with a surface integral (getting negative answer)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

**Problem.**  Let $\textbf{F}=\langle 0,0,z^2\rangle$ and let $S$ be the upper hemisphere for $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$.  Find
$$
\iint\limits_S\textbf{F}\cdot\textbf{n}\;dS,
$$
where $\textbf{n}$ is the outward normal vector.

*Attempted Solution.*  We will use the formula
$$
\iint\limits_S\textbf{F}\cdot\textbf{n}\;dS=\iint\limits_R\textbf{F}\cdot(\textbf{t}_u\times\textbf{t}_v)\;dA
$$
where $\textbf{t}=\textbf{t}(u,v)$ is a parametrization of $S$.  To find the parametrization, we use spherical coordinates as follows:
$$
\textbf{t}=\langle 2\sin v\cos u, 2\sin v\sin u,2\cos v\rangle,\;\;\;0\leq u\leq 2\pi,\;\;\;0\leq v\leq\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
Due to the fact that the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of $\textbf{F}$ are zero, we only need the $z$-coordinate of $\textbf{t}_u\times\textbf{t}_v$, which is given by
$$
(-2\sin v\sin u)(2\cos v\sin u)-(2\sin v\cos u)(2\cos v\cos u)=-4\sin v\cos v
$$
Now $\textbf{F}=\langle 0,0,4\cos^2v \rangle$, which means
$$
\textbf{F}\cdot(\textbf{t}_u\times\textbf{t}_v)=-16\sin v\cos^3v.
$$
We can now compute
$$
\iint\limits_R\textbf{F}\cdot(\textbf{t}_u\times\textbf{t}_v)\;dA
=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}(-16\sin v\cos^3v)\;dv\;du=-8\pi.
$$
However, the Divergence Theorem yields a different answer:  $+8\pi$.

I seem to be missing a negative somewhere, and I strongly suspect it has to do with the orientation of $S$.  If I take $v$ to range from $\pi/2$ to $0$ (instead of from $0$ to $\pi/2$) then it works out.  But, how would I know to orient it that way?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It is upper hemisphere and you need outward normal vector which is in positive z-direction. Your z-component of the normal vector is $-4\sin v\cos v$ which will be negative as $0 \leq v \leq \pi/2$ and so the normal vector is pointing in negative z-direction and is inward

Comment: So you should use $4\sin v\cos v$

Comment: @MathLover okay thank you